# Setting a (tricky) active class on React tabs

Tags: reactjs, tabs

I have some very basic React tabs:

```
  const tabItems = ['Tab 1', 'Tab 2'];

  function TabGroup() {
    const [activeItem, setActive] = useState(tabItems[0]);
    return (
      <>      
        <div className={styles.tabs}>
          {tabItems.map(tabItem => (
            <button
              className={activeItem === tabItem ? "on" : "off"}
              onClick={() => setActive(tabItem)}
            >
              {tabItem}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <p>Active Tab: {activeItem} </p>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Which works fine, but our project uses modules for the CSS, imported like so at the top of the file:

```
import styles from 'styles/wallet.module.scss'
```

Calling a CSS class from the wallet.module.scss means you have to reference them like this:

```
<div className={styles.foo}></div>
```

So my question is... back to the original example of my tabs, I need the className for the activeItem to take something like {styles.on} e.g.;

```
        <button
          className={activeItem === tabItem ? {styles.on} : {styles.off}}
          onClick={() => setActive(tabItem)}
        >
```

But calling them like that inside the activeItem == tabItem check throws an error:

```
./components/wallet.js
Error: 
  x Unexpected token `.`. Expected ... , *,  (, [, :, , ?, = or an identifier
    ,----
 24 | className={activeItem === tabItem ? {styles.on} : {styles.off}}
    :                                            ^
    `----

Caused by:
    0: failed to process input file
    1: Syntax Error
```

I've tried every which way of entering these but not sure which syntax magic will get me what I want here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the braces around your styles.

```
 className={activeItem === tabItem ? styles.on : styles.off}
```

The first set of curly braces indicates jsx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an actual idiot. You just can't include the curly brackets.

This works:

```
        <button
          className={activeItem === tabItem ? styles.on : styles.off}
          onClick={() => setActive(tabItem)}
        >
```